# How can I intercept ActiveRecord::Base.logger output?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, stream, rails-console

**Context:**  I am constructing a really long sql string and executing it with ActiveRecord.  When it fails, it logs out the error (which includes the original query) and takes up 5 pages of screen space.  Because I am already catching the exception, I don't need to be notified there was an error, and it just clutters the logging.  All attempts to temporarily turn off the logger or to hijack IO streams have been futile.

**Problem:** How do I prevent logging of that one exception?

**Example:** (I know a lot of this code is redundant, but my point is that even all together it doesn't work)

```
really_long_query = "select * from posts where ..."
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 10
$stderr = $stdout = $stdin = STDOUT = STDERR = STDIN = IO.new(IO.sysopen('/dev/null', 'w+'))

silence_stream(STDOUT){
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute really_long_query # TURN LOGGING OFF FOR THIS LINE
} # => still logs the exception to the console, despite all the above code
```

**My Conclusions:** Based on the above results, I assume that ActiveRecord must be using

1. A different logger *AND*
2. A stream not included on line 3

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord exceptions are like normal exceptions, you can handle them, so please try:

```
begin
  sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute really_long_query
rescue => e
  # do what ever you want to do with error
end
```

I am no able to try it now, but I guess it may be help for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jan.  I actually do have my code in a begin-rescue block already.  The exception is not the problem, the problem is that the exception is being logged to the console.  Since I am catching it and doing my own error processing, I do not need it logged and it is making my logs messy.